# Issue when trying to start minikube with virtualbox?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, minikube

I'm using the new version of MacOs Catalina, i just installed Docker, Minikube and Virtualbox. All these from Homebrew. When i try to start `minikube start`, i get following error:

```
  minikube v1.9.2 on Darwin 10.15.4
✨  Using the virtualbox driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
❗  This VM is having trouble accessing https://k8s.gcr.io
  To pull new external images, you may need to configure a proxy: 
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/networking/proxy/

  Failed to enable container runtime: enable docker.: NewSession: write tcp 
127.0.0.1:50207->127.0.0.1:50185: write: broken pipe

  minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

With `hyperkit-vm` its working fine, but not with virtualbox?
Anyone know why I am getting this problem? I did not get this error for few days ago, suddenly i get this now?

Thank for the help!

Comment: Have you used `minikube stop` before restarting it? If you want to start fresh you can run: `minikube stop`, `minikube delete`, `minikube start`.

Comment: Still same issue, also tried reinstall minikube with no luck :/

Comment: Its working fine with `hyperkit` but virtualbox wont work with minikube?

Comment: I see. Also try adding `--driver=docker` to your `minikube start` command. See [this](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/)

Comment: also runs fine with `docker`, only issue when trying to use `virtualbox`

Comment: Looks like some leftover configuration on VM side. Please try running these commands in that order: `minikube delete`, `rm -rf ~/.minikube`, `minikube start`. We need to make sure you start the cluster fresh.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: Noe, i think there might be a bug in the new version of `minikube`. I have created an issue on their github site.

Comment: Could you link that issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might a a bug from `minikube`. There is some related issue to this one on their GitHub site.

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7616

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7465

Hopefully they will fix this bug soon as possible.